# You specified `onScroll` on a <ScrollView> but not `scrollEventThrottle`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-scrollview

I am using **Scrollview of react-native** in my code.

```
<ScrollView style={styles.productlist} >
         <CarouselComponent images={images}/>
</ScrollView>
```

Its working fine on an app, with no error, and no warning but in Console I am getting the below message repeatedly:

> You specified `onScroll` on a  but not `scrollEventThrottle`. You will only receive one event. Using `16` you get all the events but be aware that it may cause frame drops, use a bigger number if you don't need as much precision.

Don't know what is missing, I have not passed onScroll props but still getting this message.
Any suggestion...

My Carousel component Code is:

```
const renderImages = (image, index) => {
  return (
    <Image
      key={index}
      style={styles.carouselImage} 
      source={{ uri: image.large }} 
    />
  );
}
const CarouselComponent = (props) => {
  const { images: { alternate = [] } = {} } = props;
  if (alternate.length > 0) {
    return (
      <Carousel
        delay={3000}
        autoplay
        style={styles.carouselLayout}
        bullets
        chosenBulletStyle={globalStyle.proDetCarSelectBullet}
        bulletStyle={globalStyle.productDetailBullet}
        bulletsContainerStyle={globalStyle.proDetCarBullet}              
        isLooped
        currentPage={0}
      >
        {alternate.map((image, index) => renderImages(image, index))}          
      </Carousel>
    );
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: What's inside the CarouselComponent / ReviewComponent ?

Comment: inside CarouselComponent rendering images, and inside ReviewComponent rendering user reviews.

Comment: Are you using a ScrollView with a onScroll method there?

Comment: Maybe the `CarouselComponent` is a ScrollView itself, can you share the `CarouselComponent` code?

Comment: No, those are just functional component that return Carousel only.

Comment: No matter if it is a functional or class component, `Carousel` is not a react-native component, so maybe this component is using a bugged `ScrollView`

Comment: Or maybe the `ReviewComponent`. Please tell us more about these components.

Comment: Even if i use only one component I am getting same message, and I am using react-native-looped-carousel npm library for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using an older version of `react-native-looped-carousel`. On github there is a [issue](https://github.com/phil-r/react-native-looped-carousel/pull/235), which was fixed 27 days ago, describing your problem.

**Fix:**

Updating to the latest version of `react-native-looped-carousel` should resolve your issue. As an alternative you can fix the error by manually adding the scrollEventThrottle. See [here](https://github.com/phil-r/react-native-looped-carousel/pull/235/files/e919bc1cf73a006e0cf2fb8daa726f442b943e1f).

Comment: I using latest version of ` react-native-looped-carousel`

Comment: @RaviSharma you are right, the fix is not released yet. You can still fix it manually.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the main `ScrollView` component needs the following code:

```xml
<ScrollView
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
  ~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in your code, the problem is contained into `react-native-looped-carousel` as an issue states here: https://github.com/phil-r/react-native-looped-carousel/issues/269

I suggest you to search for another library. React-native's code keep growing in a very fast way and every library should be updated frequently.

Just to learn something new, the `scrollEventThrottle` prop defines how many times the `onScroll` event will be fired while you scrolling. The bigger the number is, less times the event will be fired. `16` is most precise value.